# Is this durood enough?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, salawat

Is this durood enough for the reward
Allahumma salli wa sallim alaa nabbiyina Muhammad (ﷺ) should I add ﷺ at the end? Jazakallahu khair

Answer (score 1):

> Allahumma salli wa sallim alaa nabbiyina Muhammad

This is a complete durood and it doesn't require ﷺ after it. But if you are just mentioning the name of Muhammadﷺ then write at least ﷺ with it.

In terms of reward, durood Ibrahimi is of highest value.